# Warning on iOS camera opening

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am just starting out in iOS development, so for my first project, I'm developing a simple iOS application to take a picture and display it on the screen.

Here's my code, it's on line four that I get the error:

```
- (IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}
```

I get the following warning:

```
  Assigning to 'id<UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'todd_learningViewController *const __strong'
```

I don't understand the warning message and don't know how to get rid of the warning.

Thanks,

EDIT:

My header file for the class looks like this:

```
  @interface todd_learningViewController : UIViewController <UIApplicationDelegate>

  - (IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender;

  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *pictureView;

  @end
```

How should I modify it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make your class implement `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and this warning message will go away. All the methods in this protocol are optional so you will not have to modify your implementation class.

Why we have to do this is still something I am trying to figure out but for now this is the solution.

Comment: It's because `UIImagePickerController` is a subclass of `UINavigationController`. The `delegate` has to conform to both protocols because the navigation controller part of the image picker uses the same `delegate` property.

Answer (score -1):

First implement below delegates in class

```
<UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource>

@interface className : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource> {


}
```

**It should be like this**

```
@interface todd_learningViewController : UIViewController <UIApplicationDelegate,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource>{

    }

  - (IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender;

  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *pictureView;

  @end
```

Comment: Now I have four errors, in my implementation file, I have three errors on '@implementation todd_learningViewController' which are 'Method protocol not implemented' and a Semantic issue: 'incomplete implementation'. The old error still persists. Thanks!

Comment: is this u r appDelegate class, why u have implemented UIApplicationDelegate ,if not remove it

Comment: I don't understand that comment, can you explain more?

Comment: i mean to say u have implemented UIApplicationDelegate so just remove this delegate if not required then run u r application

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11934/discussion-between-rohit-dhawan-and-todd-davies)

Comment: no need `UIApplicationDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource`, and `UIPickerViewDelegate` should change to `UIImagePickerViewDelegate`